# change the sequence of items in DropDownList in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have populated the DropDownList with numeric values(items) from 1 to 10. These items appear in a sequential order. Now i want to shuffles these item 
Like Item 1 appear on 8th position
     Item 2 appear on 6th position etc
I know that i can do it using swap method but
Is there any more efficient way to do this ?

Comment: show some code, swaps seems very efficient.

Comment: For i As UShort = 0 To 10
          randomQuestionNumbers.Items.Add(i.ToString())
  Next

Comment: I want to know is there built-in method of changing the order of items in dropdownlist ?

Comment: Can you not put them in the order you want and bind that to the datalist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know `DropDownList`, so I wrote some code for `ListBox`.

```
' Up
Dim Index As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
If Index > 0 Then
    Dim Value As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem
    ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(Index)
    ListBox1.Items.Insert(Index - 1, Value)
Else
    ' Cannot move up the first item or no item selected
End If

' Down
Dim Index As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
If Index > -1 And Index < ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then
    Dim Value As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem
    ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(Index)
    ListBox1.Items.Insert(Index + 1, Value)
Else
    ' Cannot move down the last item or no item selected
End If
```